# Error Deploying node js app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed node js application to AWS EBS. When I run the app, i get the error " 502 Bad Gateway " nginx/1.6.2 . This is what i found out in the log.

env.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2015/04/21 10:52:01 [error] 3807#0: *86 connect() failed (111:      Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.4.86, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "clinicaltrials-env.elasticbeanstalk.com"

This is my package.json file

```
{
"name": "Clinical_Trial_Analytics",
"version": "1.3.2",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "express": "3.0.6",
    "stylus": "0.31.0",
    "jade": "0.27.7",
    "mongodb": "1.2.7",
    "moment" : "1.7.2",
    "emailjs": "0.3.3",
    "json2html": "1.0.0"
},
"engines": {
    "node": "0.12.0",
    "npm":  "1.1.65"
}
}
```

This is my main.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.locals.pretty = true;

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'super-duper-secret-secret' }));
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/client' }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

require('./server/router')(app);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.log("Clinical Trials server listening on port " +  app.get('port'));
})
```

I am unable to figure out the issue. Is it with the node version or any other problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be an issue with your code

Comment: Its working fine locally on 8080

Comment: What's in your Node.js log?  What's in `process.env.PORT` as far as your app sees it?

Comment: Please find the updated code.. I renamed app.js to main.js correspondingly because in elastic beanstalk, app.js is called before npm install

Comment: Solved. I just gave process.env.port. Did not use any port number.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to add the Node command at Configuration Modify software section of your beanstalk app, I can see in your app you are using the command start, so use it as node command, "npm start" that will start your app correctly, this also happens when use the folder and file bin/www to start the Nodejs server.